# Does an age confirmation overlay screen on the landing page for a porn site negatively effect SEO?

Tags: seo, cloaking, adult-content

I am creating a porn website for my client. Now because of UK laws, we need to have an enter page that confirms that the user is over 18 years old.

Now I've had a look at competitors and they are actually putting an overlay over the whole homepage, and when you click accept it then hides.

Would Google see this as you trying to "cloak" and hide text? Because essentially you are hiding everything on the website until a user clicks accept.

Can anyone advise me on the best way to go about this?

Comment: Not yet. But it likely will at some point. The popularity of various JS based overlays is really really annoying. Google is already penalizing app downloads this way and has strongly signaled that it may not end there. Google sees these as bad UX (user experience). And I do too. I cannot tell you how many sites I bounce from each day because they have annoyed me and their content is simply not worth one or two more clicks. This is NOT engagement. In your case, it is probably better be prepared to perform age checks the old fashioned way eventually.

Comment: I expect that porn sites that are required to show this type of overlay will be treated differently by Google compared to sites that show an overlay for other purposes.

Comment: closetnoc , what is the old fashioned way?

Comment: A login/registration style of page that verifies age rather than a overlay. Without age verification, the page(s) that can be accessed has images that are censored. You can use a button or something rather standard. For now, your overlay may be okay. I have not seen G take a stand on this yet except for application downloads. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Google recently announced an update to their mobile search results concerning content that is obscured by  pop ups and overlays. (or interstitials)

[Helping users easily access content on mobile](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2016/08/helping-users-easily-access-content-on.html)

They give examples of techniques that would fall foul of thier new penalty and also examples that would not be affected, one of which is:

> Interstitials that appear to be in response to a legal obligation, such as for cookie usage or for age verification.

[image]

So I think it's fair to assume if Google are ok with pop ups, or overlays for age verification on mobiles, they would be fine if used on desktop too.